# Closed form for a sequence of a language variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Question:
We developed a new language based on some rules:
The language limits all variable names to zero or more letters from the set {b, e, d} followed by zero or more digits from the set {0, 1, 2, 3}. In other words, the empty string, b, 12, bed100, and bedb2012 are all legal variable names. However, 1b and be2d are not valid variable names. There is exactly 1 legal variable name of length 0, namely the empty string. There are exactly 7 legal variable names of length 1: b, e, d, 0, 1, 2, and 3. There are exactly 37 legal variable names of length 2: bb, be, bd, b0, b1, b2, b3, eb, ee, ed, e0, e1, e2, e3, db, de, dd, d0, d1, d2, d3, 00, 01, 02, 03, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32, and 33. Your task is to find a closed-form expression for the number of legal variable names of length n in the language.

I have tried finding the sequence first so that I can find the closed-form but I am stuck in the first part, can't even go further.
Like, the difference between length 0,1,2 is 1,7,37. Every form I take, I can't find the difference `d` from it. Not only that, how am I supposed to find a closed-form for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable name of length $n$ is made up of a prefix of length $k$ made of letters, and a suffix of length $n-k$ made of digits.

The number of such prefixes is $3^k$, and the number of such suffixes is $4^{n-k}$.

Therefore, the number of variable names of length $n$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{n-k}=4^n\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac34\right)^k$$

Then use the rule for the sum of a geometric series, to get

$$4^n\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac34\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac34}\right)=4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the 1st equation you wrote which included summation.?

Comment: For example, to get a variable name of length 4, you can have
* 4 letters and 0 digits ($3^4\times4^0$ combos); or * 3 letters and 1 digit ($3^3\times4^1$ combos); or * 2 letters and 2 digits ($3^2\times4^2$ combos); or * 1 letter and 3 digits ($3^1\times4^3$ combos); or * 0 letters and 4 digits ($3^0\times4^4$ combos); The total number of combos is the sum of these, $3^04^4+3^14^3+3^24^2+3^34^1+3^44^0=\sum_{k=0}^43^k4^{4-k}$. In general, for length $n$ instead of length $4$, the sum is $\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{n-k}$

Comment: Then, note that $\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{n-k}$ equals $\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^n4^{-k}$, which equals $4^n\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{-k}$, which is $4^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{3^k}{4^k}$, which in turn is $4^n\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac34\right)^k$.

Comment: Understood, Thank you